# Why use BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization?

Tags: c#, wpf, concurrency, binding

I've implemented a custom concurrent observable collection that can be modified from multiple threads using a simple lock for all *write* operations and an array snapshot (that is created on each change from inside the lock) for all *read* operations. (See https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/210575/concurrent-observable-collection for a slightly outdated version, just to get the idea.)

As required by WPF when implementing `INotifyCollectionChanged`, I invoke the `CollectionChanged` event on the dispatcher's thread, something like this:

```
private void _notify(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (_context == null)
    {
        _invokeCollectionChanged(args);
    }
    else if (_context.CheckAccess())
    {
        _invokeCollectionChanged(args);
    }
    else
    {
        _context.InvokeAsync(() => _invokeCollectionChanged(args));
    }
}

private void _invokeCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
{
    CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, args);

    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Count)));
}
```

NOTE: `_context` is the `Application.Current.Dispatcher`.

Now I discovered `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization` and - as far as I understand the documentation - it does not help in regards of locking, but only regarding the correct invoking of the `CollectionChanged` event.

Is that correct? Should I use `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization`? What difference would it make?

Answer (score 1):

My advice is **do not** use `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization` if you plan active modifications of your data.

I used this heavily in a project, where large sets of data were loaded in a separate thread in chunks.  After loading a chunk, data was pumped into the `ObservableCollection` with `BindingOperations.EnableCollectionSynchronization` enabled.  It was also possible that user cancels the operation and starts new load of data.  In this case, we cleared the 'ObservableCollection` and started filling it anew, again all from another thread.

The result was an obscure crash every now and then.  We traced the crash down into the code of `ListCollectionView` class, which contains the locking to allow multi-thread access.  It has a subtle bug, which I couldn't report as I could not create a 100% reproduceable sample.

What we did was to redirect populating the `ObservableCollection` from the UI thread via `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`.

Better come up with your own synchronization, you will be able to test and eventually fix the code yourself.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience! I had the feeling it may be one of those framework features that are easy to use and implement, *if* the concrete requirements are pretty much *exactly* what Microsoft had in mind when building the feature.